# How can I convert this json into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have the following json

```
{

id:1,
job: {
    name:"g",
    documents:[
        {
            name: "a.pdf",
            pages: [
                {
                   detail:"page_detail_a",
                   notes=[
                      {
                        note:"note_a"
                        references: [
                            {
                                detail_a_a:'.....'
                                ...
                                detail_a_n:'.....'
                            }
                        ]
                      }
                   ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "b.pdf",
            pages: [
                {
                   detail:"page_detail_b",
                   notes=[
                      {
                        note:"note_b"
                        references: [
                            {
                                detail_b_a:'.....'
                                ...
                                detail_b_n:'.....'
                            }
                        ]
                      }
                   ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

}
```

into

```
job  name  document.name    page.detail      reference
1     g    a.pdf            page_detail_a    detail_a_a
...   ...  ...              ...              ...
1     g    a.pdf            page_detail_a    detail_a_n
...   ...  ...              ...              ...
1     g    b.pdf            page_detail_b    detail_b_a
...   ...  ...              ...              ...
1     g    b.pdf            page_detail_b    detail_b_n
```

Is this possible or I need process with for loop the json structure?

Thanks

Comment: Are there multiple pages per document?  Are there multiple notes per page?  Are the keys in the `references` list really variable like thst?

Comment: Documents, pages, notes, and references are list and can be have a lot of entries, and in another version, problaley more nested objects with fields.

Comment: Maybe start from something like this?  `pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data), record_path=['job', 'documents', 'pages', 'notes'], meta=['id', ['job', 'name'], ['job', 'documents', 'name'], ['job', 'documents', 'pages', 'detail']])`.  For `reference`, you are taking keys instead of values so you need to use some other methods.